# CAPL - Converting 4 raw bytes into floating point

Tags: type-conversion, capl

CAPL - Vector.

I receive message ID 0x110 which holds current information:

0x3E6978D5 -> 0.228

Currently I can read the data and save into Enviroment Variable to show in Panel using:

putValue(slow_current, this.long(4));

But I don't know how to convert the HEX 4 bytes into float variable, since I cannot use address or casting (float* x = (float *)&vBuffer;)

How to make this conversion in CAPL script? Thanks.

Comment: Can't you just add a DBC that contains the information that those bytes are supposed to represent a float?

That would save you from doing the conversion yourself.

Comment: Just a thought, if you use CANoe 10 or greater, you have a basic feature called Symbol Mapping in Environment tab, where you can permanently link a corelation between signals and sysvars. But since your message doesn't seem to have a signal mapping, you have to define a signal for that entire 8 byte payload, so you can reference to it in the Symbol Mapping window.

Answer (score 3):

Typically your dbc-file shall contain conversion info from raw value (in your case 4B long) to physical value in form of factor and offset definition:

[image: dbc-file editor++ screenshot]

So your physical value of current shall be calculated as follows:
phys_val = (raw_value * factor) + offset

**Note:** if you define negative offset then you actually subtracting it in equation above.

But it seems you don't have dbc-file so you need to figure out factor and offset by yourself (if you have 2 example raw values and know their physical equivalent then it shall be as easy as finding linear equation parameters -> y = ax + b).

CAPL shall look like this:

```
variables

{
    float current_phys;
    /* adjust below values to your needs */
    float factor = 0.001 
    dword offset = -1000
}
on message 0x110
{
    current_phys = (this.long(4) * factor) + offset;
    write(current_phys);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternate solution if you don't want to force transform the value:

1. You define a **sysvar** type **float(double)** and use that sysvar in the panel
   (link to it), instead of the envVar
2. or you change the type of envVar to **float(double)**.

[image]
The translation into float will be done automatically

[image: New Sysvar addition interface].

**Caveat**: usually this trick requires that the input number is also 8 bytes as the defined CAPL float range 8 bytes. *But you have this by message payload length constraint= 8bytes.*

Answer (score 0):

Does not look good, but works:

received msg: 0x3E6978D5

putValue(float4byte,interpretAdFloat(this.long(4)));

float4byte = 0.23

Answer (score -1):

i just reused Vinícius Oliveira solution to avoid creating environment variable. it worked

```
float floatvalue;
floatvalue = interpretAsFloat(HexValue);
```

input (HexValue) = 0x3fe20e3a
output(floatvalue() = 1.76606